# getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN in node js Ubuntu

Tags: server, nodejs, amazon-ec2

our company has decided to move to AWS EC2 and we moved. we are using Ubuntu 18.04. we have successfully install node and npm and also started using node js. but after few days we are getting following error

```
Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN info.payu.in
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26) {
errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'info.payu.in'
}
```

I think this error was occurred after we change instance type in AWS. 1st we where using t2.micro instance type. later we upgrade to t2.xlarge. after upgrading there we no changes in public ip and private ip. I have search on internet some said update npm to latest version, so i try to update, but getting following error

```
error request to https://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN 
registry.npmjs.org
```

we are also using load balancer and we have also added DNS record with type A in route 53. please help me for finding solution.